# Pi 4 how to insert and remove usb

Tags: raspbian, usb

I have 2 questions - apologies if they are trivial.

1. When I shut down my pi4 the led goes out but comes back on soon after.
   Is this ok/ normal?
2. I use the GUI and have had a USB stick corrupted. Can USB sticks be inserted and removed whilst the power is up?
   Do I need to use the terminal to eject it before removal.

Comment: "the led goes out" which LED - the Pi4 has several? "Can USB sticks be inserted and removed" YES - as with ALL OS you need to **eject** FIRST to avoid corruption! There is a control to do this.

Comment: The green LED will flash ten times on shutdown. After the last flash it's safe to pull the power. USB sticks should be plug'n'play. The only proviso is that you **MUST** unmount the filesystem (to ensure buffers are flushed and the device is dormant) before pulling the USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using the latest Raspbian.
The answer of your first question is yes. And it is the red one.
Your second question is not clear. But you can safe remove your device with the safe remove icon in the tray.A GUI can not corrupt your stick , but a power issue can.

Comment: Thanks, I only see a red light - the pi4 is in its box. I do not see an eject button perhaps it needs installing.

Comment: What OS you are using?

Comment: I'm using Raspbian. Just bought the pi and put it in an official case. Using noobs

Comment: I suggest you use the latest buster from raspbian.

Comment: I'm using this - just bought the pi thanks

Comment: The eject button is on the task bar (panel), usually on the right side. It looks like this: ⏏

Comment: @AlfredDominicVella Because this answers your questions, please accept it with a click on the tick on its left side. This will finish the question and it will not pop up again months for months.